# Make Flowplayer-Flash play video instantly while buffering

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, flowplayer

I am using flow player. But problem is that when I click the play button then it keeps loading and it plays the video only after loading/buffering the complete video. When complete video will be downloaded/loaded then it will start playing.

I want it to play instantly after clicking the play button.

I searched on this but did not find solution about this.

I am using following code:

```
flowplayer("player", {src:"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", wmode: "opaque"}, {
clip: {
    url: "video.mp4",
    autoPlay: true,
     autoBuffering: true
```

}
    });

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are streaming from an optimized CDN like [Amazon Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/WorkingWithStreamingDistributions.html) with support for RTMP.

Comment: I don't know about Optimized CDN. How to check if I have that?

Comment: Optimized CDN isn't a thing. I just mean make sure that the place you are streaming the video from is set up to deliver video. A file merely sitting on a server somewhere isn't enough. I use Cloudfront for my streaming video needs, but it isn't free.

Comment: But if I use HTML 5 video player then everything works perfect. But Not in flowplayer. I have video file on my server. And I am using Hostgator server.

Comment: Yes, because Flash and HTML5 video are different technologies that work differently. You can't equate them. If you want Flash video to stream efficiently, you need RTMP: http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

Comment: I have shared Hosting from Hosgtgator. Do I need special type of hosting for this?
Is there any simple solution?
I am building a Self hosted video tutorial website. So what should be the best and Simplest solution for me?

Comment: The Vidya website has video tutorials too. The way it works there is to upload the videos to the YouTube channel and simply link to them from the website. Alternatively, I've written applications that store videos on Amazon S3 (http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and then serve them to the client via Cloudfront (link above).

Comment: Actually these videos will not be free. These are the videos of courses. And students can watch online videos after purchasing the course.  If we upload it on the youtube then public will watch video in free. That's issue.

what do you say about this?

Comment: The Vidya video tutorials are free, but it is possible to make YouTube channels private (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en). Or I already mentioned the CDN solution. Anyway, Stack Overflow does not permit extended discussion threads. I suggest you do some homework on the options I mentioned and perhaps find others. Meanwhile, an upvote, or an accept if this helped you, would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your mov-atom is probably at the end of the mp4. Look into how to move that to the beginning. That will fix your problems.